# What does "str" % "str" mean in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I came across this code:

```
import sbt._ 

class AProject(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultProject(info) { 
  val scalaToolsSnapshots = ScalaToolsSnapshots
  val scalatest = "org.scalatest" % "scalatest" %
    "1.0.1-for-scala-2.8.0.RC1-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

And I'm quite confused as to what `scalatest` contains, and what the `%` does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you used Maven this is essentially the same thing but with Scala DSL. % works as a separator:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1-for-scala-2.8.0.RC1-SNAPSHOT</version>      
</dependency>
```

Read more:
http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/LibraryManagement

Answer (score 12):

It declares a dependency. In particular,

```
val scalatest = "org.scalatest" % "scalatest" % "1.0.1-for-scala-2.8.0.RC1-SNAPSHOT
```

refers to a dependency which can be found at

http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/org/scalatest/scalatest/1.0.1-for-scala-2.8.0.RC1-SNAPSHOT/

Where everything before `org` refers to the repository, which is (pre-)defined elsewhere.

It is not easy to find the implicit that enables `%` on `String`, but, for the record, it is found on `ManagedProject`, converting a `String` into a `GroupID`. In the same trait there's also another implicit which enables the `at` method.

At any rate, the implicit will turn the first `String` into a `GroupID`, the first `%` will take a `String` representing the artifact ID and return a `GroupArtifactID`, and the second will take a `String` representing the revision and return a `ModuleID`, which is what finally gets assigned to `scalatest`.

Comment: Actually, sbt checks multiple servers for the package, doesn't it?

Comment: @Raphael By default, yes, it does. I said that the dependency _can be found_ at that path, not that it is the only place it will look for. On the other hand, the stuff before `org` is what will be changing for each look up.

Comment: A follow-up question is what does double percent `%%` mean in the same case. I feel like I've seen it asked and answered here or somewhere else but I can't find it :-(