# What is the scala percent operator (%) and at method for strings do?

Tags: scala, sbt

```
val scalaToolsSnapshots = "Scala-Tools Maven2 Snapshots Repository" at "http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots"
val specs = "org.scala-tools.testing" % "specs_2.9.0-1" % "1.6.8" % "test"
```

What does this mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does str % str mean in the SBT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267127/what-does-str-str-mean-in-the-sbt)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can also simplify this declaration using the following :

```
scalaVersion := "2.9.0-1"

scalaToolsSnapshots := "Scala-Tools Maven2 Snapshots Repository" at "http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots"

specs := "org.scala-tools.testing" %% "specs" % "1.6.8" % "test"
```

`%%` will specify to sbt to use a specs version that is binary compatible with your project scala version.

You should consider using it especially if you plan to upgrade scala version or if you plan to publish a lib against multiple scala versions.

under the hood, first String is implicitly converted to a `GroupID` with `%%` method that convert next String to a `GroupArtifactId`, the following `%` creates a `ModuleID` and the last `%` adds a scope to the  `ModuleID`.

Answer (score 18):

That is [sbt](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki) (simple build tool) DSL that defines managed dependencies of project.

Format is quite similar to [maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven): first line says where to find repository, second line defines dependency like `"groupId" % "artifactId" % "version" % "scope"`

For details look at the [sbt wiki page](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Dependency-Management-Index.html) (section *Managed Dependencies*)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the sbt wiki page. I did not see this in the getting started guide

Comment: The key word that helped me understand what's going on here is DSL.  I was looking for a `%` string operator in Scala itself until I stumbled here.  The sbt wiki linked above describes what `%` does [right here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#The++key).    Specifically, *"the `%` methods create `ModuleID` objects from strings, then you add those `ModuleID` to `libraryDependencies`."*

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed sbt (simple-build-tool).

The 'at' method is defined on a string and returns a Resolver.
The '%' method is defined on a string, and returns a ModuleID.